# Windows 8 development WPF or Windows Store XAML

Tags: wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've been developing a windows store application for a windows 8 tablet (Microsoft surface). So far the application has been designed using XAML-RT/C# using a SQLite database. The application won't be released via the store, it'll be just used internally by my company.

I am however finding numerous problems with the platform. i.e. speed of the surface device, releasing versions and renewing the developer licences.

As the application is still in the development stage and no decision has been made on the final tablet I'm thinking about re-writing the application using WPF and using a full windows 8 tablet (not a RT/ARM version). This way I can use full SQL and have much more control over releasing the software.

So, my question is...

What is generally the best development platform for a full windows 8 tablet? Is it best to go with WPF or stick with the Xaml for RT?

Thanks

Comment: As of April 2013... WPF > WinRT XAML. Both in terms of framework features and deployment capabilities (ClickOnce). Time will tell whether that > sign is reversed or not...

Comment: Is >> a valid operator? :)

Comment: @HighCore can a desktop WPF application be assigned with an AUMID? doesn't it have to be a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF

- less sandbox limitations (can call any APIs)
- is currently somewhat easier to do enterprise deployment with
- has more features
- is more mature overall
- can benefit from Surface SDK 2.0 controls for great touch support on big screens

WinRT/XAML

- works on ARM devices
- is lighter and faster
- has built-in modern touch-enabled controls targeted for tablet use
- might be better suited for use on tablets overall

Overall the main benefit of WinRT is that you can use it on ARM tablets which are cheaper, lighter and more usable as tablets. WPF requires heavier devices and might be slower, but you gain the ability to access all legacy APIs.

Comment: Is lighter. Okay. Is faster, though? Doing what?

Comment: You are right, that's just speculation that when something is lighter it is also faster. I'd have to come up with a good piece of sample code to compare them.

Comment: Don't spend cycles on it. I was just antagonizing you.

Comment: So Jerry, what's your opinion on WPF vs WinRT?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend it to be fully touch screen ready then you'll have to do some extra work in WPF to get the level of UI interactivity that you get from the "metro" apps.

That being said, if you're writing a complex application that requires lots of API calls/web services and file handling then you're going to have a much easier time with WPF.